# Dart: Can't access dynamically set Element Ids

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

So I wanted to set an Id dynamically in dart, but i can't access it. `btn` will always be null. Chrome does show that the Button got the Id, but i get no Access to the Id in Dart..

```
    // extended Td html
    <polymer-element 
        name="crud-tr" extends="tr" attributes="metaData entry">   
        <script type="application/dart" src="crud-tr.dart"></script> 
    </polymer-element>
```

--

```
// extended Td Dart
@CustomTag('crud-tr')
class CrudTrElement extends TableRowElement with Polymer, Observable {
    void attached() {
        super.attached();
        TableCellElement editTd = new TableCellElement();      
        ButtonElement edit_cancel = new ButtonElement();
        edit_cancel
            ..text = "Edit"
            ..id = 'edit_cancel'
            ..onClick.listen((event) => toggleEditMode());
        editTd.append(edit_cancel);

        TableCellElement deleteTd = new TableCellElement(); 
        ButtonElement delete_save = new ButtonElement();
        delete_save
            ..id = 'delete_save'
            ..text = "Delete"
            ..onClick.listen((event) => deleteEntry());
        deleteTd.append(delete_save); 

        this
            ..append(editTd)
            ..append(deleteTd);
    }

    void toggleEditMode() {         
            ButtonElement editBtn = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#edit_cancel');
            ButtonElement deleteBtn = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#delete_save');
            /* -> Both null / Exception */      
    }

     CrudTrElement.created() : super.created() {
        polymerCreated();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `someFunc` from?

Comment: From another button, which is also dynamically added

Comment: And `someFunc` is a method of your elements class (in the same class as `attached()` above)? If yes, there seems to be something wrong with your element. How do you add the element itself? Can you please add the full Dart code + HTML of your element?

Comment: Sure. I have a tablePolymerElement and the code which I posted is from my extended Tr Polymer Element inside my PolymerTable.

Comment: Can you please add the code that shows how you add the element to the DOM, and the full code (Dart+HTML) of the element that allows to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I guess the problem is the missing `<template>` element in your elements HTML. Why do you add these elements imperatively instead of markup?. You add the elements as children not inside the shadowDom. If this is intentionally you need to use `this.querySelector()` instead of `shadowRoot.querySelector()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior (as designed). Dynamically created elements are not included in the map accessible with `$`. You need to use `shadowRoot.querySelector('#someButton');` instead.

#### Update

I guess the problem is the missing  element in your elements HTML. Why do you add these elements imperatively instead of markup?. You add the elements as children not as content of the the shadow DOM. If this is intentionally you need to use this.querySelector() instead of shadowRoot.querySelector()

Comment: Exception: The null object does not have a method 'querySelector'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'querySelector'
Receiver: null
Arguments: ["#someButton"]

Comment: I'd love to add them just in the html, but I cant. Since I'm adding `<td>` Elements in my extended tr Element, which is added in the table.html, the tds do not see the table tags and will be ignored. So the only way for me is to add them like this.  

and btw this.querySelector did work. :)

Answer (score 0):

"Exception: The null object does not have a method 'querySelector'."

Could that error possibly be because the `<polymer-element>` definition has no `<template>`? Perhaps a shadow DOM is never created in that instance, so `shadowRoot` is `null`. Just guessing here...

I wonder, also, if `this..append()` attaches elements to the shadow DOM. Seems unlikely.

Comment: I tested that and added the template tag and a content tag. But still got null on this.shadowRoot.querySelector :/

Comment: `this.shadowRoot
            ..append(editTd)
            ..append(deleteTd);`

Does work with shadowRoot.querySelector.